# minimum order based on zip code woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was trying to implement minimum order based on entered zip/pin code by the user on the woocommerce checkout page. 
I tried the following code in the theme's functions.php but still, I m not getting any desired output.

When I click on Place order button I get checkout.min.js error in the console. 
And when I reload the checkout page I am able to see the Desired Error('You did not meet the minimum order total')

I believe I have done some mistake in function.php

Rectification is highly appreciated.

```
        function check_min_order($order_id) {
              global $woocommerce;
                 $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                 $address = $order->get_address();
                 $total = $order->calculate_totals();
                 $postcode= $address['postcode'];
                 $zipcodes1 = array('400064' , '400062' , '400067');
                 $zipcodes2 = array('400054' , '400042' , '400071');

        $minOrderZip1 =500;
        $minOrderZip2 =1500;

        if(in_array($postcode, $zipcodes1) && $total <= $minOrderZip1 ){
                     wc_add_notice( "You did not meet the minimum order total. $minOrderZip1", 'error' );
                     exit;
                 }
                 if(in_array($postcode, $zipcodes2) && $total <= $minOrderZip2 ){
                     wc_add_notice( "You did not meet the minimum order total. $minOrderZip2", 'error' );
                     exit;
                 }
        }
        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'check_min_order',  1, 1  );
```

Comment: Read this document : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/

Comment: @Rahul, I have the same issue. did you find a solution?